# AWS IAM Setup for multiple users

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-iam

I have been trying to figure out for a long time how to properly configure the IAM policy so that each user can see ONLY their own resources (virtual machines, containers, buckets, etc.). So that he can create a resource and no one else can see it, delete it, etc.

I need to do this for one competition that I want to host on my account, while creating a certain number of users. The idea is for them to be "isolated" from each other and thus not break each other's quest progress.

If anyone has experienced a similar issue or has experience building a similar competition environment on the AWS platform, I would greatly appreciate your response!

Comment: Look at "Conditions" based on Tags, e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_ec2-start-stop-tags.html

Comment: @gile, I've tried to setup conditions, but can't figure out how I'm suppose to automate the process of tag assigment to resources that created by users. Is it related for resources, or user's username (something like "StringLike": [AWS:username: "Student"]) at the first place?